# How to create a function that passes valid phone numbers

Tags: python-3.x

I have to create a function that will take a string that contains a phone number and this is what i have so far:

```
def phoneCheck(number):
    if len(number) != 10:
        print('Invalid')
    if number[1:] == '+':
        print('Invalid')
    else:
        print('Valid')
```

the function has to ignore the parenthesis and the "+1" only in the beginning, the hyphen, and the periods in phone numbers but i do not know how to tell it to do that please help

Comment: take?as in "validate"? what about 999999999999999999999?   Happy Coding. SO 
is about fixing _your_ Code - not implementing your ideas. 
Please go over [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and 
[on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) again and if you have questions provide 
your code as [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What have you tried so far?  This is not the place to get your code written for you

Comment: Look at regular expression, and come again with your tries if you do not achieve it. You should be fine however

Comment: you could use https://pythex.org/ to design a regex to validate those.

Comment: post the code you have tried from your end.